# Codeigniter file upload issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to file upload a `40Mb` file but after some time an error shows ( `connection reset`). I've already set all values in php.ini What Can I do?

> upload_max_filesize = 500M
>
> max_input_time =7200
>
> memory_limit = 128M
>
> max_execution_time = 7200
>
> post_max_size = 500M

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST OF ALL**

After editing the `php.ini` restart apache.

**If this not work**

Try to put this at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '96M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

You can check them using `phpinfo()`;

Comment: this in on online server

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574260/php-connection-reset-on-large-file-upload-regardless-correct-setting

Comment: after 72% they again start from 0% and when they again at 72% error come connection reset

Comment: Maybe your hosting has an upload limit, what is your hosting?

Comment: plesk. but all the value are set

Comment: plesk is not a hosting, it is a software to manage the hosting. I asked you for the name of the web hosting company (Godaddy, ovh, bluehost, etc...)